# jpg images display trouble

Tags: html, css, image, jpeg

I have a very simple HTML / CSS image grid. All photos are different and are inside a `<figure>` tag. When the images are in jpg file format, when refreshing the page sometimes some of them are repeated or appear distorted, with another ghost image on top or dissappear. This only happens with jpg, not png. Why is this? Is there a solution?

```css
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

figure { margin: 0; }


.grid-item {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

.tm-img {
    max-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid-item figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center; 
}

.grid-item figure img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>                    
<div>

<div class="grid-item">
<figure>
<img src="https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/img/01.jpg" alt="Image 01" class="tm-img">
</figure>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
<figure>
<img src="https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/img/02.jpg" alt="Image 02" class="tm-img">
</figure>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
<figure>
<img src="https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/img/03.jpg" alt="Image 03" class="tm-img">
</figure>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
<figure>
<img src="https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/img/04.jpg" alt="Image 04" class="tm-img">
</figure>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
<figure>
<img src="https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/img/05.jpg" alt="Image 05" class="tm-img">

</figure>
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
<figure>
<img src="https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/img/06.jpg" alt="Image 06" class="tm-img">
</figure>
</div>  
</div>                                 

</li>
</ul>
```

#### Image repeated

[image: repeated image 1]

#### Image disappeared

[image: deleted image]

This is the sample [netlify html page](https://stupefied-fermi-29b354.netlify.app/)

#### Animation

Refreshing the page multiple times shows the issue.

[image: animation]

Comment: I refeshed nearly 50 times and never had an issue in Chrome.

Comment: I have it several times, Chrome and Firefox